# Correct JSON API Format On GitHub Pages

Tags: json, rest, api, github

I am looking to create a static JSON api, and host it on GitHub Pages so it can be used publicly. From my understanding, all I need is a JSON file with my data, and once I publish it to GitHub pages, it will be accessible from this URL:

```
http://username.github.io/repo_name/json_file_name
```

This is my JSON file, with some of the data.

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Walleye",
    "scientific": "Sander Vitreus",
    "environment": "Fresh Water",
    "climate": {
      "min": "",
      "max": ""
    },
    "depth": {
      "min": "0",
      "max": "27",
      "avMin": "",
      "avMax": ""
    },
    "length": {
      "common": "54",
      "max": "107"
    },
    "weight": {
      "common": "",
      "max": "11.3"
    },
    "maxAge": "29",
    "description": "Occurs in lakes, pools, backwaters, and runs of medium to large rivers. Frequently found in clear water, usually near brush..."
  },
  {
    "id": "0002",
    "name": "Northern Pike",
    "scientific": "Esox Lucius",
    "environment": "Fresh Water",
    "climate": {
      "min": "10",
      "max": "28",
    },
    "depth": {
      "min": "0",
      "max": "30",
      "avMin": "1",
      "avMax": "5"
    },
    "length": {
      "common": "55",
      "max": "137"
    },
    "weight": {
      "common": "",
      "max": "28.4"
    },
    "maxAge": "30",
    "description": "Occurs in clear vegetated lakes, quiet pools and backwaters of creeks and small to large rivers..."
  }
]
```

What I am wondering is, how my API will be accessed via the URL. I understand that `http://username.github.io/repo_name/json_file_name/` will `GET` a list of all the fish in my data.

How can I `GET` just a single fish though? For example, if I want to return walleye, which has an `ID` of 0001, can I do `http://username.github.io/repo_name/json_file_name/0001` or even `http://username.github.io/repo_name/json_file_name/walleye`? Is my JSON formatted correctly to do this? Or is a separate URL mapping file required inside my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand ("[Utilize Github Pages as JSON API](https://blog.testfairy.com/utilize-github-pages-as-json-api/)"), GitHub will allow you to get back the full content of the json file, with [contentType `application+json`](https://github.com/cben/sandbox/commit/405fd44bd2a532b7dfdfa51ec61a891975a1b7de)

That's it.

It won't serve anything else, meaning: once you have the full json content, you can process it to extract the relevant data you want from it, using [`jq` for instance](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

---

The [OP A.Burg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11530958/a-burg) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420630/correct-json-api-format-on-github-pages/56421439#comment99489684_56421439):

> I have decided to use [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/) to build an API with `node.js` and use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) for a database.
>   I will most likely be using [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to host the API.

Comment: I was worried about that. I still may end up going this route though.. Do you have another recommendation that I could use if I wanted to implement separate end points? Like would changing hosts solve this issue? Potentially using Heroku instead of GitHub?

Comment: @A.Burg Serving anything on GitHub side would use GitHub actions (https://github.com/features/actions), and I don't see any for JSON (https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions). Changing host is therefore required, one which can serve data (as opposed to GitHub which only serves repositories). Example https://jsonbin.io/, but your own Heroku service would be more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. With Heroku, I believe I would need a full fledged node (or other) app? I was hoping to just keep this API to simple JSON files, as it is just static. I may need to look into some tutorials into building an API with node. I've never made an API before, so this is all new to me.

Comment: @A.Burg Yes, https://medium.com/@purposenigeria/build-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-express-js-d7e59c7a3dfb or https://dev.to/sagar/build-a-restful-api-with-the-serverless-framework-ene could help.

Comment: For anyone interested in this. I have decided to use LoopBack to build an API with node.js and use MongoDB for a database. I will most likely be using Heroku to host the API.

Comment: @A.Burg Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve this with Jekyll to use 1 page per item, and use a separate 'index' page to get all these pages.

Effectively every fish becomes a jekyll blog post, and your index compiles all these posts.

It's definitely possible to generate .json files for these.

If you really prefer to start with giant index file and split it up, I think the only reasonable way is to write a little script that generates all the pages that you simply run before you push.

Comment: Thanks for that response. Another good option. I ended up going with node.js and using a MongoDB.